# SQL Server: what's the best way to query a table whose name is stored in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to put together a query but avoid using a cursor in order to do so.  We have PDF files stored in multiple tables. One year for each table. So we have table names such as:

```
"Files_2012", "Files_2013", "Files_2014", etc.
```

We then have a master table (called `Files`) that contains which table the file is stored in.

Here's the layout:

```
=======================================
 FILES
=======================================
 FileId | RecordId | FileTableName
---------------------------------------
 104    |  7108162 |  Files_2013
 105    |  7108162 |  Files_2014
 106    |  7108162 |  Files_2013
```

The yearly tables would then look like this:

```
=======================================
 FILES_2013
=======================================
 FileId | FileData (varbinary
---------------------------------------
 104    |  0x255044462D312E340A25E2E3CFD30D...
 106    |  0x897444462D312E340A25E2E3CFD30D...

=======================================
 FILES_2014
=======================================
 FileId | FileData (varbinary
---------------------------------------
 105    |  0x556044462D312E340A25E2E3CFD30D...
```

My query needs to return records based on the `RecordId`. So, in this example, all 3 of the `Files.RecordId` values are the same. I would need to return the `FileData` column for all 3 records, like this:

```
=======================================
 My returned records
=======================================
 FileId | FileData (varbinary
---------------------------------------
 104    |  0x255044462D312E340A25E2E3CFD30D...
 105    |  0x556044462D312E340A25E2E3CFD30D...
 106    |  0x897444462D312E340A25E2E3CFD30D...
```

How can I do this? If it helps, here's my query so far, although I may be way off. I'm storing the `FileTableName` values into a temporary table & was hoping to work with them that way, but I'm stuck after this:

```
DECLARE @recordId INT

CREATE TABLE #tmpFiles (FileId int, FileTableName varchar(100), FileData varbinary(max))

SET @recordId = 7108162

INSERT INTO #tmpFiles (FileId, FileTableName)
    SELECT FileId, FileTableName 
    FROM dbo.Files 
    WHERE RecordId = @recordId    

UPDATE t
SET t.FileData = f.FileData
FROM #tmpFiles t
INNER JOIN Files_2013 f ON t.FileId = f.FileId
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why not have just a single `Files` table with an additional `Year` column to make up for that information missing elsewhere? If you want to go on using separate tables, do a search for "Dynamic SQL" and/or `EXECUTE`. These are a means to execute a SQL statement that is in a string; i.e. instead of getting the table name out of a string into a query, put the whole query into a string, then `EXECUTE` it.

Comment: Since your data is all in the same format, it doesn't make much sense to store it in separate tables. Combine it all into one table, adding a column for the year.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't make much sense storing it this way.  However, these aren't my tables.  They were built many years ago by our parent company & the chances of being approved to change their structure are slim to none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you know table names in advance you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
DECLARE @recordId INT = 7108162;

WITH cte(FileId, FileData, Year) AS
(
   SELECT FileId , FileData, 2012 AS [Year]
   FROM FILES_2012
   UNION ALL
   SELECT FileId , FileData, 2013
   FROM FILES_2013
   UNION ALL
   SELECT FileId , FileData, 2014 
   FROM FILES_2014
)
SELECT c.*
FROM FILES f
JOIN cte c
  ON f.FileId = c.FileId
WHERE f.RecordId = @RecordId;
```

If you don't know tables names (I doubt because they have common name pattern) you need to use Dynamic-SQL but reconsider different options.

Read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm)

> SELECT * FROM sales + @yymm
>
> This is a variation of the previous case, where there is a suite of
>   tables that actually do describe the same entity. **All tables have the
>   same columns, and the name includes some partitioning component,
>   typically year and sometimes also month. New tables are created as a
>   new year/month begins.**
>
> In this case, writing one stored procedure per table is not really
>   feasible. Not the least, because the user may want to specify a date
>   range for a search, so even with one procedure per table you would
>   still need a dynamic dispatcher.
>
> Now, let's make this very clear: **this is a flawed table design.** You
>   should not have one sales table per month, you should have one single
>   sales table, and the month that appear in the table name, should be
>   the first column of the primary key in the united sales table. But you
>   may be stuck with a legacy application where you cannot easily change
>   the table design. And, admittedly, there are situations where
>   partitioning makes sense. The table may be huge (say over 10 GB in
>   size), or you want to be able age to out old data quickly. But in such
>   case you should do partitioning properly.
>
> In the following, I will look at three approaches to deal with
>   partitioning without using dynamic SQL.
>
> Possible solutions:
>
> - Partitioned Tables
> - Views and Partitioned Views
> - Compatibility Views